# SubQuery and Group by in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

This query was written in the our system some time ago but the performance of this query is getting poor with a little increase in data. My investigation shows (`CodeCount`)  where query firing another subquery causing a massive delay in execution. I need to optimize this Linq query. any help will be highly appreciated

```
  from batch in Context.VoucherCodeBatch.ToList()
                    join type in Context.VoucherCodeType on batch.VoucherTypeId equals type.VoucherTypeId
                    join voucher in Context.Voucher on batch.VoucherCodeBatchId equals voucher.VoucherCodeBatchId

                    where batchIds.Contains(batch.BatchCode)
                    group new
                    {
                        batch.BatchCode,
                        batch.CreationDate,
                        type.VoucherTypeName,
                        voucher.AllowedCount,
                        voucher.ValidFrom,
                        voucher.ValidTo,
                        batch.VoucherCodeBatchId,
                        voucher.VoucherCode
                    }
                        by new { batch.BatchCode }
                        into uniquebatch
                        select new Batch
                        {
                            BatchCode = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().BatchCode,
                            CreationDate = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().CreationDate,
                            TimesAllowed = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().AllowedCount,
                            ValidFrom = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().ValidFrom,
                            CodeCount = ((from c in Context.Voucher.ToList()
                                          where
                                              c.VoucherCodeBatchId ==
                                              uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().VoucherCodeBatchId
                                          select c).Count()),
                            ValidTo = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().ValidTo,
                            CodeType = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().VoucherTypeName,
                            VoucherCodeBatchId = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().VoucherCodeBatchId
                        });
```

Comment: That `ToList()` in there means that this query is requesting *all* Voucher rows from the database and filters in memory. Try removing it.

Comment: I would recommend doing such queries in SQL on the DB side.

Comment: I agree with Ewald.  Maybe even making it into a View that you can then select on much easier in LINQ.  A lot of times, just because you can do it in LINQ doesn't mean it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The first big problem is the `ToList()` right in front of an ObjectSet<> (the table collection in EF).

Never do that, the `ToList()` force EF to bring all data to memory before process the query. (Like @Daniel Hilgarth coments).

Other detail is use a get property in front of `FirstOrDefault()` like in line:

```
BatchCode = uniquebatch.FirstOrDefault().BatchCode,
```

Use `First()` instead `FirstOrDefault` in this case. like:

```
BatchCode = uniquebatch.First().BatchCode,
```

Your query will be like this:

```
from batch in Context.VoucherCodeBatch/*.ToList()*/
join type in Context.VoucherCodeType on batch.VoucherTypeId equals type.VoucherTypeId
join voucher in Context.Voucher on batch.VoucherCodeBatchId equals voucher.VoucherCodeBatchId
where batchIds.Contains(batch.BatchCode)
group new
    {
        batch.BatchCode,
        batch.CreationDate,
        type.VoucherTypeName,
        voucher.AllowedCount,
        voucher.ValidFrom,
        voucher.ValidTo,
        batch.VoucherCodeBatchId,
        voucher.VoucherCode
    }
by new { batch.BatchCode }
into uniquebatch
select ( delegate
    {
        // If you put a operation in a query that operation will be
        // processed all times. Bacause that i removed this line from
        // the where statement.
        var vcBatchId = uniquebatch.First().VoucherCodeBatchId;

        return new Batch
            {
                BatchCode = uniquebatch.First().BatchCode,
                CreationDate = uniquebatch.First().CreationDate,
                TimesAllowed = uniquebatch.First().AllowedCount,
                ValidFrom = uniquebatch.First().ValidFrom,
                CodeCount = ((
                    from c in Context.Voucher/*.ToList()*/
                    where c.VoucherCodeBatchId == vcBatchId
                    select c).Count()),
                ValidTo = uniquebatch.First().ValidTo,
                CodeType = uniquebatch.First().VoucherTypeName,
                VoucherCodeBatchId = uniquebatch.First().VoucherCodeBatchId
            }
    });
```

If this improvement not be good enough, You will need change this query to SQL. But I believe this improvement will perform much better.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. What does mean by delegate. I exactly copied the above code and compiler is complaining about select(delegate) "type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select' "